# Hotplug at boot in OpenWRT

Tags: linux, openwrt, hot-plug

I want to run some scripts at boot. I tried a lot of things but couldn't achieve.

Here is the OpenWRT boot sequence : https://openwrt.org/docs/techref/preinit_mount

After taking a look at this link i tried to make some changes to my `/etc/init.d` , i added my script in `/etc/init.d`. It looks like this :

```
avahi-daemon   dropbear       log            rpcd           system
boot           firewall       mjpg-streamer  samba          telnet
cron           **gpio.sh**        mountd         sysctl         uhttpd
dnsmasq        led            network        sysfixtime     umount
done           linkit         odhcpd         sysntpd        yunbridge
```

gpio.sh is my script. And it doesn't do anything. Am i missing something here ? Anybody can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. After inspecting carefully the boot sequence , i created my script in `/etc/init.d` and made a symlink in `/etc/rc.d` after that my script ran at boot.